# Braintree Payments requestPaymentMethod hangs

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am trying to get the javascript V3 version of Braintree Payments running against sandbox, and am having a problem with the requestPaymentMethod hanging when I provide a valid sandbox cc.

The following displays the page and successfully displays the "RequestPaymentMethod Error" alert when I do not provide a cc, but hangs (with fast a green progress "stripe" scrolling across the screen under the Pay with Card header) when the valid 4111-1111-1111-1111 cc is entered.

Note - I am trying to do this by dropping a file into the browser (ie. file://...) instead of http or https - that worked with the script tag dropin.

---

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Braintree Payments Test - JS3</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://assets.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.9.2/css/dropin.min.css" id="braintree-dropin-stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div align="center"> <h1>Braintree Payments Test - JS3</h1></div>


            <div id="dropin-container"></div>
            <button id="submit-button">Purchase</button>

            <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.9.2/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
                braintree.dropin.create({
                    authorization: <sandbox tokenizationKey>,
                    container: '#dropin-container'
                }).then(function(dropinInstance) {
                    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        alert("requesting payment method");
                        dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod().then(function(payload) {
                            alert("Recvd nonce: " + payload.nonce);
                        }).catch(function(requestPaymentMethodError) {
                            alert("RequestPaymentMethod Error: " + requestPaymentMethodError);
                        });
                    });
                }).catch(function(createErr) {
                    alert("Create Error: " + createErr);
                });

            </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: have you tried any debugging? i.e. check the browser **developer** tools console for errors, for example

Comment: Once you have an error from the debugger, please post back here.

Comment: There is no error - the debugger shows the  dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod() call being made, but never returns.  I think the issue is with my sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Due to how Braintree's JavaScript SDK relies on `postMessage()`, you will need to run your application via HTTP or HTTPS in order to avoid the issue you're experiencing. This is because with `postMessage()` `file://` cannot be used as a security restriction;

Comment: No problem-- glad to have helped